# Facebook PHP SDK not allowing to login a user

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

All,
I'm using wordpress and trying to have my user login with facebook. In my header.php for Wordpress I have the following code:

```
define('123', '123');

//uses the PHP SDK.  Download from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '123',
  'secret' => '12345',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$uid = $facebook->getUser();
if ($uid) {
    try {
        $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $uid);
        $qry = "Select user_id, role from event_details where email_address='$userInfo[email]'";
        echo $qry;
        $result = mysql_query($qry);
        $resultrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($resultrows>0){
            $resultset = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $resultset['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['role'] = $resultset['role'];
            $target = "http://www.website.com/event_choices";
            header("Location:". $target);
        }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
}else{
    echo "not logged into facebook";
}

if ($uid) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'next'=>'http://www.website.com/event_choices'
    ));
}
```

Then when I'm creating a page actually in Wordpress I have the following code:

```
<?php if ($uid): ?>
<?php echo "Welcome, ".$uid['first_name']. ".<br />"; ?>
<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">
  <img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z2Y31/hash/cxrz4k7j.gif">
</a>
<?php else: ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">
    <img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zB6N8/hash/4li2k73z.gif">
  </a>
<?php endif ?>
```

This displays the login button but whenever I click on the button nothing happens. When I look at the source code the $loginUrl isn't being populated. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing a scope when generating your login URL, this is where all the application permissions are passed. Take a look:

```
$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'scope'         => 'email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown',
        'redirect_uri'  => 'http://www.website.com/event_choices'
    )
);
```

For more info take a look at the API reference [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/).

Also, when working with Facebook sometimes it's important to get some output from FB to see what could possibly be the issue. You can do this by wrapping your code like so:

```
try {
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    //you can also put your loginURL generation code here to see if you get an error
} catch(Exception $o){
    print_r($o);
}
```